# how to get folder size which consists of files in aws using java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

lets think we have bucket with name "bucket1" and inside that having a 
folder with name 'new folder'
Inside 'new folder' are files
new folder/a1.pdf-->2mb
new folder/a2.pdf-->2mb
new folder/new folder2/b.pdf-->3mb

when we use amazons3client.listObjects("bucket1","new folder")---->it 
will return the list of files and folders inside that for each 's3object' 
there is 'size' parameter i can loop through all those s3 objects and i 
can get folder size but it is heavy operation.

/* will you please any another way to get folder size*/

Answer (score 1):

There is not another way.

The "folder" is not a container in S3 so it has no size, itself.